# What do the Data Tip icons in Visual Studio 2015 mean?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2015

I hovered over an object in the debugger and saw this:

[image: Data Tip]

All the properties on the object are of type `int?` and I would have expected them all to have the spanner (wrench) icon. What do the blue brick with a no-entry sign (if that's even what it is) mean?

Here is the source code, just in case:

```
public class QuestionnaireDestinationViewModel
{
    public int? TicketID { get; set; }
    public int? TicketTemplateID { get; set; }


    public int? T
    {
        get { return this.TicketID; }
        set { this.TicketID = value; }
    }

    public int? TT
    {
        get { return this.TicketTemplateID; }
        set { this.TicketTemplateID = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It means "yet another nullable bug", that powerful weapon of mass destruction.  The icon is for an internal field instead of a property. The debugger had a history of trouble with it, VS2015 fixed some but added some new ones back.  We can't help you fix debugger bugs, file a feedback report at connect.microsoft.com